# What is the default for the sudoers file on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, sudo, sudoers

When I try to use sudo on my laptop, it says

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 502, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Since I recently manually edited the file, I wanted to reset it to the default. What does it look like with the root user and admin as a sudoer, with no others? Please give the entirety of the file!

EDIT:
okay, i reset the file. I still get the error. How do i fix that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about OS X system administration, not programming. apple.stackexchange.com would be a better site.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running OS X 10.10.2 (14C109). Here's the entirety of my `sudoers` file, which I’ve never edited:

```sh
# sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
# Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
# that prevent sudo from running.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Defaults specification
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

**ETA:** It sounds like you might have edited this file without using visudo, and the permissions got messed up. UID 502 means you own the file, not root, and so sudo is getting confused and bailing out.

Once you’re edited the file, you should run either `chown root /etc/sudoers` or `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` as root to restore the file’s correct permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the default

```
# sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
# Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
# that prevent sudo from running.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Defaults specification
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

To fix the permissions of the sudoers file you can run these commands:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Also you can run "Repair Disk Permissions" in Disk Utility by selecting your disk drive on the left bar and going to the First Aid tab.

Comment: okay, I repaired disk permissions in Disk Utility, and now I get `sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 45
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting` How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a bad copy/paste into your sudoers file.  Try deleting all lines in your sudoers file and paste this back in.  I've also posted this on pastebin if that's easier.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3eU9vFeM

Comment: Also make sure there is no newline at the end of the file.  The very last line should be this and not a blank line:

# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now

Comment: i noticed the exact opposite thing: no new line = Error `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 45 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 45
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting`